# Swift UITableview cell search not working

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to Implement search option for my UITableview. Here, I am using custom cell within my UITableview. In my array data I am adding section also. How to fix this?

My Code Below

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

          var allDetails:[(String,[String])] = []
          var searchResult:[(String,[String])] = []
          @IBOutlet weak var tableVIew: UITableView!
          @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            allDetails = [("Vadavalli",["Vadvalli", "Mullai Nagar", "P.N.Pudhur"]),
                              ("R.S.Puram",["Lawly Road", "Kowly Brown", "D.B Road"]),
                              ("Town Hall",["Raja Street", "Gandhipark", "Five corner road", "Main Town Hall"])]
            searchResult = allDetails    
          }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return searchResult.count
          }

          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return searchResult[section].1.count
          }

          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return searchResult[section].0
          }

          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
            if cell == nil{
              cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            }
            cell?.textLabel?.text = searchResult[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]
            return cell!
          }

          func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) { // SEARCH NOT WORKING
             if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
                    searchResult = allDetails.map({ (areaTitle:$0.0,areas:$0.1.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText) })) }).filter { !$0.1.isEmpty}
                    //self.tableVIew.reloadData();
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What is this `filterNow` function? It seems you should implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `searchBar(_:textDidChange:)`. This is called every time that the search bar's text changes. You can then reference the text in the search bar and filter `allDetails`. From here you can simply reload your `UITableView`.

Comment: @DavidChopin Could you please post some code. It will help me more. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it was 3am local time when you replied, so I was asleep. I just posted an implementation of `searchBar(_:textDidChange:)` that will ensure your filtering and reloading of the table view will be called every time that the search bar text changes. Be sure to set your search bar delegate in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `searchBar(_:textDidChange:)`. This will call every time your search bar's text changes. Within this method, we can filter `allDetails` and reload our table view.

We will essentially move all of the code in your `updateSearchResults(for searchController:)` method to the `searchBar(_:textDidChange:)` delegate method.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
    var allDetails:[(String,[String])] = []
    var searchResult:[(String,[String])] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var tableVIew: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //New line of code! Be sure to set your search bar's delegate in viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        allDetails = [("Vadavalli",["Vadvalli", "Mullai Nagar", "P.N.Pudhur"]),
                  ("R.S.Puram",["Lawly Road", "Kowly Brown", "D.B Road"]),
                  ("Town Hall",["Raja Street", "Gandhipark", "Five corner road", "Main Town Hall"])]
        searchResult = allDetails
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return searchResult.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResult[section].1.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return searchResult[section].0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = searchResult[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    //Let's get rid of this function
    /*
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        // SEARCH NOT WORKING
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            searchResult = allDetails.map({ (areaTitle:$0.0,areas:$0.1.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText) })) }).filter { !$0.1.isEmpty }
            //self.tableVIew.reloadData();
        }
    }*/

    //And implement the UISearchBarDelegate method. This method fires every time that the search bar's text changes
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchResult = allDetails.map({ (areaTitle:$0.0,areas:$0.1.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText) })) }).filter { !$0.1.isEmpty }
        self.tableView.reloadData();
    }
}
```